# Get string inside brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to fetch the string inside the square bracket, which is given as array

```
u16 arrayName_1[8][7]
```

I have python code which can find the 1-Dimensional array and get the character inside squre brackets.

```
var = 'u16 arrayName_1[8]'
index = re.split('\[(.*?)\]', str(var))
```

index[0] will give 'u16 arrayName_1'.

index[1] will give '8'.

Problem:
I want to get string inside brackets of 2D array. i tried below code but it is not desired result.

```
var = u16 arrayName_1[8][7]
index= re.split('(\[.*\])$', str(var))
```

index[0] will give 'u16 arrayName_1'.

index[1] will give '[8][7]'. This is wrong result.

I want output like:

index[1] = '8'

index[2] = '7'

Comment: Have you tried *matching* with your pattern? [`re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', str(var))`](https://ideone.com/JFfHYD)

Comment: No, I dint try for re.findall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use your own pattern in [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to grab all the contents inside `[...]`:

```
import re
var = 'u16 arrayName_1[8][7]'
index = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', var)
print(index) # => ['8', '7']
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JFfHYD)

To only match digits inside, use `\[([0-9]+)]` regex. Also, you do not have to escape the `]` symbol outside the character class, and you should consider using raw string literals to define your regex patterns to avoid confusion with unescaped backslashes.

Comment: Note: This does not work if the index itself has an index, as in `foo[bar[1]]`. (This was not a requirement, just wanted to point out the limitations...)

Comment: Yeah, that is why I also suggested `\[([0-9]+)]`.